# Accurev: How to purge all changes including external files on a workspace?

Tags: accurev

Is there a command to simply purge all files including external files on a workspace, instead of creating a list of all files using `accurev stat` command and dealing with each kind separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

External files are not purged, you delete them.

Otherwise, you need to run the stat command to generate the list of elements you want purged.